# SQL-> multibuscador Access (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Tengo un formulario en Access que me sirve para buscar herramientas (brocas en el ejemplo) en una BBDD.

He construido el buscador para que se pueda operar con entre 0 y 4 variables a tener en cuenta (0 variables seleccionadas = el formulario muestra todas las brocas)

El buscador cuenta con 4 selectores de las diversas propiedades de la broca.

La consulta SQL se basa en los 4 campos OCULTOS que definen la selección, ya que si se dejara un selector vacío, la consulta SQL no funcionaría. Por esta razón, los campos ocultos siempre están auto rellenados con un * o con un 0 en el caso de la altura de trabajo que es un valor numérico mayor o igual a (>=) en vez de un campo igual a (=).

Mi idea, es que si el usuario selecciona 1 o 2 variables, lo campos ocultos completen la sentencia SQL añadiendo un * (toda la selección) en el campo correspondiente.

[image: Vista buscador]

En el caso de la foto, solo se habría seleccionado el diámetro de la broca a buscar dándonos igual el sentido de giro, la altura de trabajo y el tipo de broca.

Como podréis observar, los campos ocultos contienen * para que la consulta SQL no falle al encontrarse un valor *null*.

La sintaxis SQL:

```
SELECT HERRAMIENTA.Ubicacion, HERR_BROCA.diametro, HERR_BROCA.Sentidogiro, HERR_BROCA.altura_trabajo, HERR_BROCA.altura_total, HERR_BROCA.modelo

FROM HERRAMIENTA, HERR_BROCA

WHERE herramienta.id_herramienta = HERR_BROCA.id_broca

AND HERR_BROCA.diametro = (forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_diametro].value)

AND HERR_BROCA.Sentidogiro = (forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_sentidogiro].value)

AND HERR_BROCA.altura_trabajo >= (forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_alturatrabajo].value)

AND HERR_BROCA.modelo = (forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_modelo].value)
;
```

El problema que tengo es que el access no me reconoce por ejemplo el caracter * cuando estamos hablando de diámetro de brocas al ser un campo numérico. Dice que es demasiado compleja la expresión.

¿Hay alguna forma de que el access permita hacer una multiselección de esta manera? ¿Alguna idea de como podría solucionarlo?

Escribir aquí es como hacer chuletas para el examen, aprendes haciéndolas... y se me ocurre cambiar el diámetro de broca de campo numérico a texto pero... ¿Hay alguna otra forma?

Esto podría seguir dando problemas si reconociera el * como texto en si mismo en vez de como (* = "cualquier cosa que existe en la tabla")

EDITO CON LA MEJORA PROPUESTA POR EL COMPAÑERO #Esei

```html
SELECT 
    HERRAMIENTA.Ubicacion, 
    HERR_BROCA.diametro, 
    HERR_BROCA.Sentidogiro, 
    HERR_BROCA.altura_trabajo, 
    HERR_BROCA.altura_total, 
    HERR_BROCA.modelo 
FROM 
    HERRAMIENTA, 
    HERR_BROCA 
WHERE 
    (HERRAMIENTA.id_herramienta)=(HERR_BROCA.id_herramienta)
And
    ((HERR_BROCA.diametro) Like IIf(((forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_diametro.value)=1),(forms!BuscaBrocas.buscar_diametro.value),'*'))
And 
    ((HERR_BROCA.Sentidogiro) like IIf(((forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_sentidogiro.value)=1),(forms!buscabrocas.buscar_sentidogiro),'*')) 
And 
    ((HERR_BROCA.altura_trabajo)>=(forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_alturatrabajo.value)) 
And 
    ((HERR_BROCA.modelo) like IIf(((forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_modelo.value)=1),(forms!buscabrocas.buscar_modelo),'*')) 
;
```

De esta manera, si seleccionamos un valor para utilizalo en el buscador, las variables ocultas pasaran de 0 a 1 para indicar al bucle IIF que se encuentra dentro de la consulta SQL que entre en la opcion: "coger el valor del formulario", en vez de la opcion "usar * porque la variable en cuestion no se esta utilizando en el buscador"

Como observareis, para poder utilizar un asterisco (*) en el buscador he tenido que sustituir el operador = por el operador like.

La consulta funciona, mostrando los datos en un buscador en tiempo real que se actualiza conforme modificamos las variables a buscar.

El problema que surge en este momento es que:

**Si el buscador arroja cero registros, el formulario desaparece y se queda en blanco totalmente**
Esto debe de ocurrir porque el origen de datos es una consulta sql en la configuracion del propio sub-formulario que muestra los resultados.
Cuando los datos devueltos son cero, el cuerpo del formulario se vuelve blanco y solo muestra el encabezado del mismo.

Un saludo, y muchas gracias de nuevo #Esei

Comment: Creo que podrías hacerlo con [IIf](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-silnm-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3). Por ejemplo, para el diametro déjalo como numero y comprueba si es Null. Si lo es, que devuelva 0 y si no, que devuelva lo que has escrito. Algo tipo `AND HERR_BROCA.diametro = IIf(forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_diametro].value="";0;forms![BuscaBroca].[sql_diametro].value)`. Lo mismo para el resto.

Answer (score 3):

Esta hecho.

Es posible con un campo numerico comparar con: numeros (obvio) y * (no numero) en una consulta SQL que se lanza desde el ACCESS.

Hay que utilizar el poerador LIKE en vez del operador =.

Hay que tener mucho cuidado con los simbolos " y ' puesto que son esenciales para que el compilador haga su "magia" sin errores.

Mi consulta sql:

```sql
SELECT *

FROM herr_broca

WHERE 
diametro_trabajo Like IIf(forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_diametro.value=1,forms!BuscaBrocas.buscar_diametro.value,"*") 
And 
altura_trabajo>=forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_altura_trabajo.value And sentido_giro Like IIf(forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_sentido_giro.value=1,forms!BuscaBrocas.buscar_sentido_giro.value,"*") 
And 
modelo Like IIf(forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_modelo.value=1,forms!BuscaBrocas.buscar_modelo.value,"*") 
And ubicacion Like IIf(forms!BuscaBrocas.sql_ubicacion.value=1,forms!BuscaBrocas.buscar_ubicacion.value,"*");
```

De esta manera consigo que en un formulario sin clickar botones, el sub-formulario de busqueda me filtre las herramientas en tiempo real en cuanto el operador cambia el campo diametro, el campo tipo de broca... o una combinacion de los campos que componen el buscador (multibusqueda por ejemplo de una broca del diametro 4 con giro 'horario' que este en el almacen 3).

Esencial si quieres en el propio buscador permita actualizar (alta, baja o modificacion) sin mucho codigo adicional, seleccionar los datos de una tabla o consulta directa sobre tabla en vez de una vista o consulta sobre varias tablas (este sesgundo caso no permite actualizar en los formularios puesto que el access se 'lia' a la hora de hacerlo automaticamente).

Un saludo,
gracias por la ayuda compañeros.
Espero que mi duda pueda servirle a alguien mas.